# Unable to use chain method inside of for loop

Tags: rust, iterator, chain

as I understand it, Calling the chain method on an iterator consumes it and returns a new type. This is a problem, because I need to chain multiple iterators together inside a for loop. My first attempt:

```
pub fn convert(s: String, num_rows: i32) -> String {
    let mut iter = s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i, c)| {
        if i % ((num_rows as usize - 1)*2) == 0 {Some(c)} else {None}});
    for n in 1..num_rows as usize {
        iter = iter.chain(
            s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i,c)| {
                let cycle = (num_rows as usize - 1)*2;
                if i % cycle == n || i % cycle == cycle - n {Some(c)} else {None}
            })
        );
    }
    iter.collect()
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:5:16
   |
2  |       let mut iter = s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i, c)| {
   |  _____________________________________________________-
3  | |         if i % ((num_rows as usize - 1)*2) == 0 {Some(c)} else {None}});
   | |                                                                      -
   | |                                                                      |
   | |______________________________________________________________________the expected closure
   |                                                                        the found closure
4  |       for n in 0..num_rows as usize {
5  |           iter = iter.chain(
   |  ________________^
6  | |             s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i,c)| {
7  | |                 let cycle = (num_rows as usize - 1)*2;
8  | |                 if i % cycle == n || i % cycle == cycle - n {Some(c)} else {None}
9  | |             })
10 | |         );
   | |_________^ expected struct `FilterMap`, found struct `std::iter::Chain`
   |
   = note: expected struct `FilterMap<Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>`
              found struct `std::iter::Chain<FilterMap<Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>, FilterMap<Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:6:46: 9:14]>>`
```

no big deal, I thought. I'll just let it infer the type inside the loop, like this:

```
pub fn convert(s: String, num_rows: i32) -> String {
    let mut iter;
    for n in 0..num_rows as usize {
        iter = iter.chain(
            s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i,c)| {
                let cycle = (num_rows as usize - 1)*2;
                if i % cycle == n || i % cycle == cycle - n {Some(c)} else {None}
            })
        );
    }
    iter.collect()
}
```

This gives me a new error saying I need to declare a type:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:4:16
  |
2 |     let mut iter;
  |         -------- consider giving `iter` a type
3 |     for n in 0..num_rows as usize {
4 |         iter = iter.chain(
  |                ^^^^ cannot infer type
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

So, after that I tried adding in the type annotations from the earlier compiler error:

```
use core::str::Chars;
use core::iter::*;
```

```
let mut iter: Chain<FilterMap<Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>, FilterMap<Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>>;
```

This looks quite ugly, and it still didn't work:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:6:16
   |
6  |           iter = iter.chain(
   |  ________________^
7  | |             s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i,c)| {
8  | |                 let cycle = (num_rows as usize - 1)*2;
9  | |                 if i % cycle == n || i % cycle == cycle - n {Some(c)} else {None}
10 | |             })
11 | |         );
   | |_________^ expected struct `std::iter::FilterMap`, found struct `std::iter::Chain`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::iter::Chain<std::iter::FilterMap<std::iter::Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>, std::iter::FilterMap<std::iter::Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>>`
              found struct `std::iter::Chain<std::iter::Chain<std::iter::FilterMap<std::iter::Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>, std::iter::FilterMap<std::iter::Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, _>>, std::iter::FilterMap<std::iter::Enumerate<Chars<'_>>, [closure@src/lib.rs:7:46: 10:14]>>`
```

So, what am I missing? How can this work?

Comment: it looks like that declaration should have two more `>` at the end

Comment: Ah, yup, it looks like you are right. but it also is asking for a second type argument before those two `>` and I'm not sure what to put in there. I'll edit the question with the updated code and issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that directly because you would need a different type at each loop iteration: `Chain<FilterMap, FilterMap>` the first time, then `Chain<Chain<FilterMap, FilterMap>, FilterMap>` the second time, then `Chain<Chain<Chain<FilterMap, FilterMap>, FilterMap>, FilterMap>` the third time, and so on.

This issue can be solved by boxing the iterators:

```
pub fn convert(s: String, num_rows: i32) -> String {
    let mut iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=char>> = Box::new (s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i, c)| {
        if i % ((num_rows as usize - 1)*2) == 0 {Some(c)} else {None}}));
    for n in 1..num_rows as usize {
        iter = Box::new(iter.chain(
            s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i,c)| {
                let cycle = (num_rows as usize - 1)*2;
                if i % cycle == n || i % cycle == cycle - n {Some(c)} else {None}
            }))
        );
    }
    iter.collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9555c031effe26ca17bb2b912a53a6fa)

Which gives you a lifetime error about `n` being borrowed by the closure, easily fixed by adding `move`:

```
pub fn convert(s: String, num_rows: i32) -> String {
    let mut iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=char>> = Box::new (s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(|(i, c)| {
        if i % ((num_rows as usize - 1)*2) == 0 {Some(c)} else {None}}));
    for n in 1..num_rows as usize {
        iter = Box::new(iter.chain(
            s.chars().enumerate().filter_map(move |(i,c)| {
                let cycle = (num_rows as usize - 1)*2;
                if i % cycle == n || i % cycle == cycle - n {Some(c)} else {None}
            }))
        );
    }
    iter.collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=287d628e4d3c165cf0bc38a44537ad5a)